# Can someone help fix my drag & copy code?

Tags: javascript, svg, copy, drag

I almost give up;( try the snippet, Managed to get it to work only half way'(

I know the problem is in how I am handling listeners and the event.targets. But I can't figure out what is wrong;(

Goal is to make sure all "inventory" class elements can be drag & copied. All "draggable" class elements can be drag & dropped.

I managed to get things working via "double click". Basically first click the DragnClick function creates draggable. Then next click and drag - does the trick.

But how to make it just with one click? how do I pass drag event over to Draggable?

```js
//var morphUIon = false;
var morphTarget = null;
var drag = null;
var canvas = {};
var inventory = {};
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
inventory = document.getElementById("inventory");

window.onload = function() {
  for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("inventory")[i].addEventListener("mousedown", DragnCopy);
  }
}

function DragnCopy(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var copy = e.target.cloneNode(true);
  copy.classList.remove("inventory");
  copy.classList.add("draggable");
 canvas.appendChild(copy);
 drag = new Draggable(copy);
}

function Draggable(elem, event) {
  this.target = elem
  this.clickPoint = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.lastMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.currentMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.dpath = this.target.getAttribute("d")
  this.subclass = this.target.getAttribute("subclass")
  this.target.pathPoints = parsePathToPoints(this.dpath, this.subclass)
  this.target.addEventListener("dblclick", this)
  this.target.addEventListener("mousedown", this)
  this.handleEvent = function(evt) {
        switch (evt.type) {
            case 'mousedown':
                evt.preventDefault()
                this.clickPoint = globalToLocalCoords(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
                this.target.classList.add("dragged")
                this.target.ownerSVGElement.addEventListener("mousemove", this.move)
                this.target.ownerSVGElement.addEventListener("mouseup", this.endMove)
                break;
            case 'dblclick':
                evt.preventDefault()
                if (morphTarget) {
                  if (morphTarget!=this.target) {
                  morphTarget.classList.remove("morphed")
                  this.target.classList.add("morphed")
                  morphTarget = this.target;
                  } else {
                    return;
                  }
                } else {
                  morphTarget = this.target
                  this.target.classList.add("morphed")
                }
                //Morph(this.target);
                break;
        }
  }
  this.move = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    var p = globalToLocalCoords(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
    this.currentMove.x = this.lastMove.x + (p.x - this.clickPoint.x)
    this.currentMove.y = this.lastMove.y + (p.y - this.clickPoint.y)
    this.target.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + this.currentMove.x + "," + this.currentMove.y + ")")
  }.bind(this)
  this.endMove = function(evt) {
    this.lastMove.x = this.currentMove.x
    this.lastMove.y = this.currentMove.y
    this.target.classList.remove("dragged")
    //this.target.setAttribute("pointer-events", "all")
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.move)
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.endMove)
  }.bind(this)
  function globalToLocalCoords(x, y) {
    var p = elem.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
    var m = elem.parentNode.getScreenCTM()
    p.x = x
    p.y = y
    return p.matrixTransform(m.inverse())
  }
}

function Morph(elem) {
  console.log(elem); 
}

function parsePathToPoints(d, sub) {
  var darray = [];
  var pathPoints = {};
  switch (sub) {
            case 'circle':
              darray = d.replace(/M|A|Z/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              pathPoints.p0 = {"x": darray[0], "y": darray[1]};
              pathPoints.p1 = {"x": darray[0]+darray[2], "y": darray[1]-darray[3]};
              pathPoints.p2 = {"x": darray[7], "y": darray[8]};
              pathPoints.p3 = {"x": darray[0]+darray[2], "y": darray[1]+darray[3]};
              pathPoints.p4 = {"x": darray[2], "y": darray[3]}; // = radius used in the circle path
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'curve4':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length-2; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                };
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'curve3':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number)
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                }
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'curve2':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                }
              return pathPoints;
            break; 
            case 'curve1':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                }
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'cubic':
              darray = d.replace(/M|C/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                    pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
               }
              return pathPoints;
            break; 
    }
}

function pointsToPath(pathPoints, pathSubclass) {
    console.log("joining "+pathPoints+"for a "+pathSubclass);
}
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color: #fff; 
}
svg {
    position: fixed; 
   top:0%; 
   left:0%; 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%;  
}
.inventory {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: black;
  cursor: move;
}
.draggable {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: blue;
  cursor: move;
}
.dragged {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: green;
  cursor: move;
}
.morphed {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: red;
  cursor: move;
}
.lines {
 stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 8,5;
  stroke-width: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
path
{
 stroke-width: 3;
 stroke: #000;
 stroke-linecap: round;
}
path.fill
{
 fill: #3ff;
}
#canvasBackground {
 fill: lightgrey;
}
#inventoryBackground {
 fill: grey;
}
#morphUIrect {
    fill: none; 
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-dasharray: 10,5;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
.label {
  fill: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg id="svg"
  height="480"
  width="480"
 viewbox="0 0 480 580"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
<rect id="canvasBackground" width="480" height="480" x="0" y="0" pointer-events="all"/>
<rect id="inventoryBackground" width="480" height="100" x="0" y="480" pointer-events="all"/>

<g id="inventory">
<path class="inventory" subclass="circle" d="M30,530 A35,35 1 1,1 100,530 A35,35 1 1,1 30,530" />
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve4" d="M125,500 Q155,490 185,500 Q195,530 185,560 Q155,570 125,560 Q115,530 125,500" />
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve3" d="M245,495 Q275,520 280,560 Q245,570 210,560 Q215,520 245,495" />
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve2" d="M305,515 Q345,475 385,515 Q345,555 305,515"/>
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve1" d="M305,550 Q345,580 385,550"/>
<path class="inventory" subclass="cubic" d="M420,495 C470,530 380,530 425,565"/>
</g>

<g id="canvas">
</g>
  
<g id="morphUI">
<rect id="morphUIrect" visibility = "visible" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0"></rect>
<line id="l0" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l1" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l2" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l3" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l4" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l5" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l6" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l7" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<circle id="0" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="1" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="2" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="3" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="4" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="5" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="6" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="7" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="8" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="10" _x="0" _y="0"/>
</g>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't figure out what's wrong either. Would you mind explaining what exactly doesn't work as you expect it to. To me this snippet seems to work.

Comment: Well see what the goals I mentioned -in this snippet one can't move draggable elements after first drag.

Comment: I edited the snipped with the best I could do. Basically now everything works fine except that it requires 2 clicks to do the drag & copy. First click to copy second click to start dragging. How do I merge events? so that user could click and drag from the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two separate mousedown event handlers.  The second one (that starts the drag) is only added after you clone the inventory item.

If you want the drag to start when you click the inventory, then you need to move the "start dragging" code to the first mousedown handler.

In the example below, I have just moved it to a function called 'startMove()' which I call from the first mousedown handler.

```js
//var morphUIon = false;
var morphTarget = null;
var drag = null;
var canvas = {};
var inventory = {};
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
inventory = document.getElementById("inventory");

window.onload = function() {
  for (i=0;i<6;i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("inventory")[i].addEventListener("mousedown", DragnCopy);
  }
}

function DragnCopy(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var copy = e.target.cloneNode(true);
  copy.classList.remove("inventory");
  copy.classList.add("draggable");
  canvas.appendChild(copy);
  drag = new Draggable(copy);
  drag.startMove(e);
}

function Draggable(elem, event) {
  this.target = elem
  this.clickPoint = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.lastMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.currentMove = this.target.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
  this.dpath = this.target.getAttribute("d")
  this.subclass = this.target.getAttribute("subclass")
  this.target.pathPoints = parsePathToPoints(this.dpath, this.subclass)
  this.target.addEventListener("dblclick", this)
  this.target.addEventListener("mousedown", this)
  this.handleEvent = function(evt) {
        switch (evt.type) {
            case 'dblclick':
                evt.preventDefault()
                if (morphTarget) {
                  if (morphTarget!=this.target) {
                  morphTarget.classList.remove("morphed")
                  this.target.classList.add("morphed")
                  morphTarget = this.target;
                  } else {
                    return;
                  }
                } else {
                  morphTarget = this.target
                  this.target.classList.add("morphed")
                }
                //Morph(this.target);
                break;
        }
  }
  
  this.startMove = function(evt) {
    this.clickPoint = globalToLocalCoords(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
    this.target.classList.add("dragged")
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.addEventListener("mousemove", this.move)
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.addEventListener("mouseup", this.endMove)
  }

  this.move = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    var p = globalToLocalCoords(evt.clientX, evt.clientY)
    this.currentMove.x = this.lastMove.x + (p.x - this.clickPoint.x)
    this.currentMove.y = this.lastMove.y + (p.y - this.clickPoint.y)
    this.target.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + this.currentMove.x + "," + this.currentMove.y + ")")
  }.bind(this)
  this.endMove = function(evt) {
    this.lastMove.x = this.currentMove.x
    this.lastMove.y = this.currentMove.y
    this.target.classList.remove("dragged")
    //this.target.setAttribute("pointer-events", "all")
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.move)
    this.target.ownerSVGElement.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.endMove)
  }.bind(this)
  function globalToLocalCoords(x, y) {
    var p = elem.ownerSVGElement.createSVGPoint()
    var m = elem.parentNode.getScreenCTM()
    p.x = x
    p.y = y
    return p.matrixTransform(m.inverse())
  }
}

function Morph(elem) {
  console.log(elem); 
}

function parsePathToPoints(d, sub) {
  var darray = [];
  var pathPoints = {};
  switch (sub) {
            case 'circle':
              darray = d.replace(/M|A|Z/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              pathPoints.p0 = {"x": darray[0], "y": darray[1]};
              pathPoints.p1 = {"x": darray[0]+darray[2], "y": darray[1]-darray[3]};
              pathPoints.p2 = {"x": darray[7], "y": darray[8]};
              pathPoints.p3 = {"x": darray[0]+darray[2], "y": darray[1]+darray[3]};
              pathPoints.p4 = {"x": darray[2], "y": darray[3]}; // = radius used in the circle path
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'curve4':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length-2; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                };
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'curve3':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number)
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                }
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'curve2':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                }
              return pathPoints;
            break; 
            case 'curve1':
              darray = d.replace(/M|Q/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
                }
              return pathPoints;
            break;
            case 'cubic':
              darray = d.replace(/M|C/g, "").replace(/,/g, " ").split(" ").map(Number);
              for (i=0, j=1, o=9; i<darray.length; i+=2, j+=2, o++) {
                    pathPoints["p"+(o-9)] = {"x": darray[i], "y": darray[j]};
               }
              return pathPoints;
            break; 
    }
}

function pointsToPath(pathPoints, pathSubclass) {
    console.log("joining "+pathPoints+"for a "+pathSubclass);
}
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color: #fff; 
}
svg {
    position: fixed; 
   top:0%; 
   left:0%; 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%;  
}
.inventory {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: black;
  cursor: move;
}
.draggable {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: blue;
  cursor: move;
}
.dragged {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: green;
  cursor: move;
}
.morphed {
  fill: transparent;
 stroke: red;
  cursor: move;
}
.lines {
 stroke: green;
  stroke-dasharray: 8,5;
  stroke-width: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
path
{
 stroke-width: 3;
 stroke: #000;
 stroke-linecap: round;
}
path.fill
{
 fill: #3ff;
}
#canvasBackground {
 fill: lightgrey;
}
#inventoryBackground {
 fill: grey;
}
#morphUIrect {
    fill: none; 
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-dasharray: 10,5;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
.label {
  fill: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg id="svg"
  height="480"
  width="480"
 viewbox="0 0 480 580"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
<rect id="canvasBackground" width="480" height="480" x="0" y="0" pointer-events="all"/>
<rect id="inventoryBackground" width="480" height="100" x="0" y="480" pointer-events="all"/>

<g id="inventory">
<path class="inventory" subclass="circle" d="M30,530 A35,35 1 1,1 100,530 A35,35 1 1,1 30,530" />
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve4" d="M125,500 Q155,490 185,500 Q195,530 185,560 Q155,570 125,560 Q115,530 125,500" />
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve3" d="M245,495 Q275,520 280,560 Q245,570 210,560 Q215,520 245,495" />
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve2" d="M305,515 Q345,475 385,515 Q345,555 305,515"/>
<path class="inventory" subclass="curve1" d="M305,550 Q345,580 385,550"/>
<path class="inventory" subclass="cubic" d="M420,495 C470,530 380,530 425,565"/>
</g>

<g id="canvas">
</g>
  
<g id="morphUI">
<rect id="morphUIrect" visibility = "visible" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0"></rect>
<line id="l0" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l1" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l2" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l3" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l4" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l5" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l6" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<line id="l7" visibility = "hidden" class="lines" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"/>
<circle id="0" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="1" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="2" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="3" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="4" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="5" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="6" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="7" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="8"/>
<circle id="8" visibility = "hidden" class="control" cx="0" cy="0" r="10" _x="0" _y="0"/>
</g>
</svg>
</body>
```